# Design pattern for adding Code modules without recompiling

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Hi I need some ideas on would be an appropriate design pattern for the following scenario

I have a game engine and the game has different levels which execute those a modules for each level, but I want the ability for my game to pick up new levels dropped in the Game play folder. Each new level would require a new game play module for instance. I do not want to change the code of the game engine instead I would just want to add the new level to some kind of a config and the game should be to execute the new game play module for that level

In my head I am thinking either the Command Pattern or the  composite pattern

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically known as *add-ins* or *plug-ins*. In .NET, that's what the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) was originally designed to address, although I'm not sure exactly what the status on that technology is...

In general, you may not need a configuration file for this. Instead, your application can designate a directory where it'll look for add-ins. In .NET, these would be compiled assemblies, while in Java I suppose they would be .jar files.

Once the application has discovered the add-ins, it can use Reflection to scan them for implementations of application-specific interfaces or base classes (I recommend interfaces).

To support instantiation and composition, you might want to consider using a DI Container that'll compose all the add-ins.

Since multiple add-ins could supply implementations of the same interface, the Composite design pattern does come in handy.